# Is it good idea to shift from Web Development to Windows Development

Tags: windows

What do you think Is it good idea to shift from Web Development to Windows Development

Comment: What are you developing right now PHP, ASP.NET, JSP? And what are you planning to develop? .NET, c/win32, VB? Why the shift and why now?

Comment: Should I shift from eating vanilla ice cream to chocolate ice cream?  As Merkuro pointed out, you need to give more context for this question to get a helpful answer.

Comment: @David HAust, Sure you should. Vanilla is for children, real geeks only eat chocolate.

Answer (score 7):

From what I've seen web development is definitely in high demand right now.  Most of the job listings ask for ASP.NET, PHP, etc.  There are definitely companies out there that do Windows apps, but with the rate at which technology changes, web apps seem to be the easiest way for companies to keep up.

Answer (score 5):

only if you need to...

Web is good for some things and windows for other things

Comment: Best answer in my honest opinion.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Web applications are a fad that will pass.

Comment: Although this is sarcasm, you may be more right than you think.  Doubt it, but, this industry likes repeating history every 10 years and totally reversing trends in favor or new bells/whistles.

Comment: Silverlight looms as the technology that will bring peace and prosperity to web UIs everywh--bahaha sorry I couldn't say that with a straight face.

Comment: @Marc... I've been saying this for a while and everyone thought I was crazy. Glad to see I'm not the only one.

Comment: @Josh: Doesn't make you any less crazy though ;)

Answer (score 3):

uh, I think you should go with whatever kind of development you enjoy?

Answer (score 2):

I would think the other way. Web applications can be run in all operating systems with a web browser. Hence, they have much coverage, and you need not worry about deploying to various systems. Code it once (taking care of the myriads of browsers!) and you are done!

Also, the best thing apart from everything is that, you can release a new version/fix bugs, without the user even knowing about it. Whereas, if it were to be a Windows (or any other, for that matter), you will have to let the users know about the update and let them manually download/get the files and patch.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, four reasons:

- The Interwebs has no applications, except Facebook apps.
- Powerful applications have local file access with full 8.3 filenames.
- More people use Windows than Internet Explorer.
- Customers pay more when software comes in pretty shrink-wrapped boxes.

But seriously, **what is your point?**

The very fact that you are asking this question on a **programming website** should tell you something.

Edit:
I was obviously being silly - but I think I each of my points are valid, if you can see past the bad jokes.

Comment: Saw past the "bad" jokes... +1 ;-)

Comment: You can upload files to web app and do the same with it, i never had a need to do anything on the filesystem in enterprise app. If you make app for sale(is that more or less than 5% of devs?) you can also sell web apps(fogbugz). they are easier to install(one machine only) and you dont have to worry about installation envoriment.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

If You have the skill, knowledge and You are willing to learn new things ( lots of new things ) - You might give it a try. I was helping to develop django based web app, I created rather simple pylons project - but writing web apps and creating programs in languages such as C++ is two different things.

Creating simple working example in Python takes little time - when I first switched to C++, it took hours, before my program would compile, run and do what it was meant to do.

If You know languages is witch You want to develop on Windows - why not give it a try? Web apps are on the rage, as Ben Alpert written in one of the answers, but I think that feeling good and comfortable with what You are doing is also important.

If You don't know languages used for Windows development, but as You had written, You have background with programming, I will give You an advice: register at [topcoder.com](http://www.topcoder.com) or similar site and try to solve algorithm problems posted there. Knowing data structures and algorithms is better than knowing a little about every language - and besides, You will learn the language of choice with this rather fast.

Answer (score 1):

You can develop windows application even UI is not required such as job.
If you do not very like UI issue, it sound good.

Comment: customers need UI, i can even imagine console app that is not for power users.

Answer (score 1):

A few years ago I shifted from desktop to web development and do not regret this.

If you're into win development, you will always need to have somebody to give you a job. With web, you can be a player on your own where your job is a natural extension of your hobby. I have it right now and I enjoy this harmony.

Comment: like we all, when i was starting php and cgi were the only web players and now its for small companies.

Answer (score 0):

No. Web applications are all the rage right now.

Answer (score 0):

I firmly believe you should have compatible technology stacks for both web and desktop application development and be proficient in both.

That way you can produce an application, either on the web, or for the desktop, and then create a version for the other medium by adding a new user interface tier to the application.  This will allow you to target a larger customer base.

Answer (score 0):

Career-wise, you mean? No way -- web apps are all the rage right now. If you mean for a specific app, it may well be worth having a uniform web-service server back-end AND both specialized (maybe, though not necessarily, Windows-specific) AND generalized (browser-based) client front-ends -- but that doesn't spell **shift**, does it?

Answer (score 0):

i am a web developer and also looking abit at windows development. my opinion, so far, is they (web vs win) are good for different things. eg. theres google docs vs ms office. but ms office is much more powerful (at the moment). i think there seem to be an increasing demand for web applications now. esp. when u got smart phones etc. u need to work everywhere not just on desktops, this is where web application can do better.

abt changing from web to windows, i say no. i am a web developer and thinking of learning abit abt windows dev, not not totally change to windows dev. windows dev which seems to pay more :) and is also getting more powerful. something good abt windows dev. is speed (Desktop rather than thru server) and ease of distribution (if u dont have a big/powerful server to host all clients app) u just need an installer or exe

Comment: However enterprise window app and web app do different things. think of facebook and window app that works like facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Wev Development can be annoying, but Desktop Development has its issues too. for example something might not work on one specific computer, because of its configuration - in web you only has to worry about different browsers and different versions. JavaScript is not cool(however jQuery made it cool), but at least you dont have to worry about/use threads(like in Desktop App).

Web Apps are the future and the more experience you got with is - the better.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking if you should, from a career perspective, shift to Windows or whether you, as a company, are looking to decide between a Windows based solution and a Web based Solution?

Anyhow, here are my notes on both perspectives:

From a personal (career) point of view:

- I think both will remain sound career alternatives for sometime into future. Windows market share is still significant and there are still a lot of requirements for building native Windows application.
- The specific answer depends on where you are, your industry and how much that industry looks to build web apps vs Windows apps.
- If you have skill sets that applies to a particular set of applications, then that should tilt the decision in that direction.

From a company perspective:

- Whether users are from multiple OSes or single OS (the very obvious question)
- Whether you like to give away the binary (Windows) or whether you like to host it and make multiple iterations on the code (web)
- Ability to recruit and retain top talent in either case in your region and budgets. Believe me, this is more important than you think
- Also, whether your application can be made easier by using the relative merits of Windows (closer to hardware) or Web (APIs, Open Authentication, Web containers, Cloud Computing) should also be taken into account.

Answer (score 0):

Easy - do both.  Pick the right solution for the task at hand rather than getting too hung up on going down a specific route as there are pros & cons to each.

Answer (score 0):

I think that, in the near future, there will be a strong relationship (that will form a vibrant ecosystem) between three principal forms of applications (In order of relevance):

- Web Based
- Mobile
- Desktop

My personal advice is to study and learn the basis of all, maybe choosing your favorite one to master.